# FrameLayout inside RelativeLayout not showing

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have the following issue. In my layout, which is used as a list item, I have a `FrameLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout`. In the Graphical Layout in Eclipse it appears just as expected, however, when I debug in a real device (HTC One V Android 4.0.3 in this case), the `FrameLayout` does not appear at all (but the area it occupies is visible). In the Adapter I do not play with the visibility, I just change the background color between two colors.

Here is my layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="130dp" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/entryType"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/color_punch_in_darker"
    android:gravity="center" >
</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/color_black"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/clock"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/time"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_clock" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/company"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/clock"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/entryType"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:hint="@string/string_NA"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/color_grey_darker"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/project"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/company"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/entryType"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:hint="@string/string_NA"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/color_grey_darker"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/note"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/project"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/entryType"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:hint="@string/string_NA"
    android:textColor="@color/color_grey_darker"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my adapter, the part where I interact with the layout for changing the color (**and I assure you is the only part of the code where I interact with the `R.id.entryType` view**), I have the following code:

```
if(entry.isInEntry())
    viewHolder.entryType.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.color_punch_in_darker));
else
    viewHolder.entryType.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.color_punch_out_darker));
```

The Graphical layout shows the following, which is the correct

[image: Graphical Layout Image]

But when I debug, the following appears (**the arrow and the border shows the area where the color should be, but instead only the width appears**)

[image: Debug Layout]

Many thanks in advance since I do not know what else I can check.

Comment: Try removing frame layout and adding view class

Comment: @PulkitSethi I already tried that before. Just tried again right now just to check, but still nothing.

Comment: ok can u putur getview function where u change colors, u know u have to reset them like if(condition) { // color1} else {//color2} else is important may b ur missing that

Comment: why not you just use a `View` instead of `FrameLayout` ?

Comment: @PulkitSethi - Thanks for the heads up. As you can see I edited the question and added the adapter part where I interact with the R.id.entryType view. Like I said, I don't change the visibility, and as you can see, I didn't forget the else part :)

Comment: @Shoshi - Even being a FrameLayout or a View, the same problem occurs...

Answer (score 1):

Use foreground attribute for FrameLayout (with no children) instead of background 
or add a View (fill_parent) to the FrameLayout
or set the FrameLayout's paddingLeft to 15dp (same as your width)

FrameLayout will measure itself as 0 unless it has a reason to give itself dimension.  The layout_widith/height is still reserving it space, but it has no children to draw and your background is a color (therefore it's dimensionless)

Comment: after posting this question I began to think it could have something related to the measurements as you referred, since the RelativeLayout ignores some things, e.g layout_weight.

I tried your ideas, but no luck either :( Foreground, padding or view inside the FrameLayout. Am I missing something? I used to do layouts based on LinearLayouts, but acording to Android's best practices it's bad, so I decided to try with a RelativeLayout as they say. But I guess I'll be going to the LinearLayouts if nothing works :S

Comment: well, in this case you're using a relative layout as a horizontal linear layout, so it would be just as efficient with a linear layout.  LinearLayout costs two passes, with weights it costs three passes, but RelativeLayout always costs four layout passes, so it's actually worse for simple cases. LL is costly when it's nested and RL allows you to avoid nested LL's.

Answer (score 0):

try layout_alignParentLeft="true", add some margin for testing for Framelayout and then have the textboxes in reference to that